Is natural theology pseudo-science, according to some demarcation criterion proposed in the literature?
From Wikipedia:

Natural theology, once also termed physico-theology, is a type of theology that seeks to provide arguments for theological topics (such
as the existence of a deity) based on reason and the discoveries of
science, the project of arguing for the existence of God on the basis
of observed natural facts, and through natural phenomena viewed as
divine, or complexities of nature seen as evidence of a divine plan
(see predestination) or Will of God, which includes nature itself.
This distinguishes it from revealed theology, which is based on
scripture and/or religious experiences, also from transcendental
theology, which is based on a priori reasoning.[citation needed] It is
thus a type of philosophy, with the aim of explaining the nature of
the celestial motors, or gods, or of one supreme god, that are
responsible for heavenly motion. Aristotle's tractate on metaphysics
claims to demonstrate the necessary existence of an unmoved prime
mover.
For monotheistic religions, this principally involves arguments about
the attributes or non-attributes of a deity, and especially the
deity's existence, using arguments that do not involve recourse to
revelation.
The ideals of natural theology can be traced back to the Old Testament
and Greek philosophy. Early sources evident of these ideals come from
Jeremiah and the Wisdom of Solomon (c. 50 BC)and Plato's dialogue
Timaeus (c. 360 BC).

Natural theology aims to establish theological truths by reasoning from facts of nature and science, without invoking purported revelations. At first glance, it might seem like a discipline that deeply values science and the study of the natural world, as it confines itself to these domains to draw inferences about theology. Yet, I don’t think anyone would classify natural theology as science. Does this imply that natural theology is pseudo-science, and if so, according to what demarcation criterion?
Note that this question is closely related to the demarcation problem, which Wikipedia defines as follows:

In philosophy of science and epistemology, the demarcation problem is the question of how to distinguish between science and non-science. It also examines the boundaries between science, pseudoscience and other products of human activity, like art and literature and beliefs. The debate continues after more than two millennia of dialogue among philosophers of science and scientists in various fields. The debate has consequences for what can be termed "scientific" in topics such as education and public policy.


Just to repeat myself (again…) Popperism is largely discredited in the philosophy of science, and the concept of 'pseudoscience' is essentially void and no longer used in academia. We can talk about how 'scientific' something is by focussing on its relationship to empirical observations, but 'pseudoscience' is an intentionally pejorative term designed to imply bad faith on the part of its purveyor. It's not an analytical term at all, and remarks nothing except the speaker's prejudgements.

For something to be pseudo-science, it must first claim to be science. Do natural theologists claim to be doing science? I don't get that impression.

People do sometimes purvey things in bad faith, and one common way is to pretend to be using the scientific method when in fact they are not. What is the preferred term used in academia to describe this?

No. Regardless of the demarcation criterion, pseudo-science must be something that claims to be science, and natural theology does not. It does share some ideas of rational investigation with sciences and uses their input, but the subject is explicitly beyond the natural world that sciences study.

It seems to me that the main point in science is that one is willing to be wrong, and in religion, one is not. So if we look at examples of 'scientists' who failed at science, one that comes to mind is Albert Michaelson, who would not believe even the results of his own very carefully performed, precise and correct experiments, because he had a different foregone conclusion. Conclusions come after examining the evidence, not before, just like in a court of Law.

If by science, you mean modern empirical science, natural theology is not science, but then again neither would philosophy be science in that sense.

Natural theology, based on the criteria commonly used to evaluate pseudoscience, may not fully qualify as pseudoscience but can share certain overlapping characteristics.
Criteria of Pseudoscience and Assessment of Natural Theology:
Testability:
Pseudoscience often presents claims that are not testable. Natural theology deals with philosophical arguments and concepts like the existence of God or the ultimate purpose of the universe, which are difficult to test using empirical scientific methods. This makes it appear similar to pseudoscience in some respects.
Reliance on Reasoning Over Empirical Evidence:
Natural theology is primarily based on philosophical reasoning (e.g., the argument from design or the cosmological argument) and less reliant on empirical evidence. This is a feature often found in pseudoscience as well.
Lack of Falsifiable Predictions:
Scientific theories must offer predictions that can be tested and potentially falsified. Many arguments in natural theology are inherently unfalsifiable because they operate within the realm of metaphysics.
Resistance to Change and Criticism:
Pseudoscience tends to resist scientific criticism and change. Natural theology sometimes presents its claims in ways that are immune to scientific critique, as it operates outside the scientific domain.
Key Differences:
Unlike pseudoscience, natural theology does not claim to be empirical science or rely on scientific methods for validation.
It primarily addresses philosophical and metaphysical issues that are beyond the scope of science, aiming to provide theological or philosophical explanations rather than scientific ones.
In conclusion, natural theology is not inherently pseudoscience but may appear similar in certain aspects, as it does not meet the rigorous criteria of scientific methodology.

What I wonder about is, if someone is looking at issues that are beyond the scope of science, why do they keep trying to bring it down to the level of a science again? You can't sail a ship with longer and longer ropes tied to the dock. Cast Off!

The boundary between science and pseudoscience is fuzzy, and it sounds like you're saying that natural theology is sitting on that fuzz.

@Barmar -- Popper's view was that there is a boundary between science and pseudoscience, but there is no boundary between philosophy, informal empiricism, or the empirical humanities and science.  That instead those all blend into each other without a clear delineation.  As naturel theology is an effort to do theology according to the truth principles of philosophy in general, and of empiricism in specific, natural theology falls into that suite of "no boundary" fields vs. science.


The first quote from wikipedia emphasizes that “natural theology”
seeks to provide arguments and that it sees or views phenomena in a
certain view. Hence it is not science but the attempt to interpret
observations in a certain way. Not the observation is doubtful but
the interpretation is questionable.

Natural theology is no science at all, at most it pretends to rely
on science.
Broadly speaking, science follows the method

observation,

explaining by a general theory,

predicting the result of actual
or planned observations,

and corresponding confirmation or
refutation of the theory.


That's the demarcation criterion to non-science.

But theology does not explain the mechanism behind the phenomena.
Its basic model is anthropomorphic and anthropocentric.
Theological claims are often immune against refutation when taking refuge to the final answer a "miracle” or a “mystery”.



Typo: mystery, at least in US English.

@keshlam Thanks, corrected.

Natural theology's premise is that our world is not a mystery, but that God and religion are supported by naturalism.  That SOME religious theology asserts mysterianism is irrelevant to this question about natural theology.

@Dcleve natural theology does not at all rely on naturalism, specially since their metaphysical principles are often at odds with each other. Aristotelian brands, for example, deny the primacy to "laws of nature" which is the cornerstone of naturalism, describing such laws as merely abstractions of the behavior of substances and therefore with no power to be the governing forces of the universe.

Point 3 is question-begging at best, mere opinion at worst. Aristotle's unmoved prime mover (mentioned in the OP) is the conclusion of a deductive argument which, given Aristotelian act and potency, purports to explain how change is possible. To believe such arguments to be unsound is irrelevant to the OP, since the question deals with the methodology of the field.
Furthermore, to rely on "miracles" or "mysteries" (in a non-derogatory sense) is the scope of revealed theology, so NT arguments do not ever appeal to them.

@Mutoh -- The nature of our universe is an open question in naturalism.  It is just an empirical and reasoning investigative attitude and agenda.  Whether the fundamental aspect of our universe are a set of "laws" or "properties" or "materials" or "emanations" is what naturalism would evaluate.  One can start with a thesis, and treat that as a Latakosian Research Programme, but if one is actually doing natural theology, then concluding that Programme is effectively refuted has to be a possible conclusion of the study.

@Dcleve it's not that open, it's characteristic of naturalism to presuppose a denial of the supernatural. And that's my main point: natural theology is not committed to a philosophical branch which is at odds with it in principle (unless, perhaps, your theology is pantheist).

@Mutoh -- It is a characteristic of naturalISTS to deny the existence of the non-material, this is not a feature of methodological naturalism, however.

The debates on the nature of science in the middle and late 20th century established that it is not at all the field of study that determines if something is science or not.  It is instead methodology and attitude.   One can approximate what science is by spelling out a methodology.  But Popper's and Lakatos' methodologies could not be universally generalized to all of the science.  Their definitions of the methodology of science were good approximations, but that ultimately what determines whether an activity is science or not is an attitude of the people pursuing it.  Specifically a) do the people pursing it only look for confirmations of their preferred views, or b) do they search aggressively for counter-evidences, and then take these counter-evidences seriously as questions that need to be answered, often by modifying the basic thesis being studied?
If the people pursuing a field only do a), and claim to be doing methodological naturalism, then no, they are doing pseudoscience or something closely related.  If they do b), then what they are doing is related to science. I used "related" because in the liberal arts such as history, or in informal empiricism such as fletching, can look for confirmations, or for counterexamples, experiencing the split of intentions.  But neither approach will actually be science, or pseudoscience, but will instead be the related equivalent in the humanities or craftsmanship skills.
The questions in natural theology are primarily philosophic questions, not scientific ones, so natural theology is also not quite in the category of science.
But it IS subject to the pseudo-research divide between honest research and dogma-driven rationalizations.  I have seen people who do natural theology fall on both sides of that divide.  That makes the answer complex.  Some natural theologians are doing the equivalent of pseudoscience, and others are doing the equivalent of science.  To figure out which category a natural theologian falls within, one needs to dig into the details of what that natural theologian is saying.


I don’t think anyone would classify natural theology as science.

[Raises hand] Ooo, ooo, I would!
The perceived-by-many failure of natural selection to explain the complexity of even the inside of a cell is considered by some to be evidence of intelligent design.
If accurate, which is plausible, and this model is not a science, then science has defined itself, Godel-like, to include a true proposition that can never be proved within the system. For a system dedicated solely to discovering the truth, that seems rather a paradox.
The main objection to calling this a science arises from the assumption that this "Creator" would be a deity — presumably one (singular, male), whose intention we have to determine, will we have to obey, and person we have to worship.
Ballocks.
Unless we're the first ones to exist, someone was here before us. And they almost certainly had a billion years of evolution on us. Clarke's original statement in Profiles Of the future was:

Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic. Anything developed beyond that is indistinguishable from God.

Creating an expanding  universe from nothing by balancing complex conjugates space against time and mass against distance is exactly the kind of thing you'd expect these creatures to do.

Lose the theological context, and Natural Theology is revealed to be a science.
What could this science look into? Is it a science without a subject?
Intent and attention.
I'll go out on a limb and infer intent. I'm willing to believe for now, until I have reason to believe otherwise, that this Creator wasn't just screwing around with the control panel and did it by accident.

Also, we might notice the periodic cycles of evolution. Changes happen about every million years when all features change at once in the same direction. Scientists call this punctuated evolution, and their explanation of it is very feeble. It resembles an explanation you'd have to come up with if there was no explanation but you had to come up with one anyway or they'd chop off your head.
They nudge us at least once every million years.
So we can infer attention.

So what of Dawkins' objection, that it doesn't explain the creation of God?
Not my problem. Ask God. I just work here.
All ID does is infer the existence of a creator from observation, and what can be inferred from that. It has nothing to say about anything else.
See? Natural Theology is a science.


This makes me imagine the plot for a sci fi novel, where the Discovery Institute finds ironclad evidence that some aspect of cell biology could not have arisen through natural selection, but they are ignored because, you know, intelligent design is just fundamentalist pseudoscience right? So humanity fails to infer from available evidence that life on earth was actually constructed artificially and seeded by intelligent aliens many millenia ago.

@MissUnderstands give it to the guy or gal you were going to and tell them to figure that part out!
